# Non-mutually-blocking ROS and Qt event loops in the same program

Tags: c++, qt, event-handling, ros, qt-signals

I am developing a multithreaded ROS application involving `Qt::QThread`-inherited objects producing signals triggering ROS publishers in the ROS node activated in the `main()` function. Qt signals and the event loop are handled by `Qt::QCoreApplication` How can one properly organize the connection between the application objects and runner functions? In the ordinary application `Qt::QCoreApplication.exec()` and `ros::spin()` functions are blocking.

Comment: See also here: https://www.anycodings.com/1questions/4664798/ros-qt-gui-how-to-distribute-the-threads

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite easy. It is needed to install `SIGINT` signal handler function that will control the sequence of starting and stopping event loops:

```cpp
// POSIX signal handler prototype section
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Qt section
#include <QCoreApplication>

// ROS section
#include <ros/ros.h>

// SIGINT handler function
void handle_shutdown(int s)
{
    ROS_INFO("Shutting down node...");
    ros::shutdown(); // Step 1: stopping ROS event loop
    QCoreApplication::exit(0); // Step 2: stopping Qt event loop
}

int main(int argc, char** args)
{
    // SIGINT handler setup
    struct sigaction sigIntHandler;
    sigIntHandler.sa_handler = handle_shutdown;
    sigemptyset(&sigIntHandler.sa_mask);
    sigIntHandler.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sigIntHandler, NULL);

    // Instantiating Qt application object
    QCoreApplication app(argc, args);
    // Instantiating ROS node object
    ros::init(argc, args, "witmotion_ros", ros::InitOption::NoSigintHandler);
    ros::NodeHandler node("~");

    // Running ROS non-blocking event loop
    ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(2);
    spinner.start();

    // Running Qt event loop: blocking call
    int result = app.exec();

    // Waiting for signal handler's return
    ros::waitForShutdown();

    // Exit code: from Qt
    return result;
}
```

The option `ros::InitOption::NoSigintHandler` instructs ROS application object to skip the installation of its own `SIGINT` handler. This kind of setup allows using freely both Qt signals, events and ROS callbacks without mutual blocks and race conditions. However, the code model is not totally thread-safe, so it is mandatory to handle synchronization of the data in case of bidirectional exchange.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ROS` but I'm pretty certain calling `QCoreApplication::exit(0);` from within an asynchronous signal handler is *not* safe.

Comment: @G.M. It is generally true. If your Qt application handles long threaded operations with critical sections it is your responsability to synchronize them well. In my case Qt part handles threaded poller, so the data flow is unidirectional and quitting is safe enough from both Qt and ROS sides.